# Why doesn't this simple PHP if statement work, and how can I correct it?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This if else statement does not work: (in this situation it displays 'x is euqal to null')

```
<?php

$x = 0;

if ($x == 'null'){
    echo 'x is euqal to null';}

else if ($x == 0){
    echo 'x is equal to zero!';}

else if ($x == 1){
    echo 'x is equal to one!';}

?>
```

My reason for needing this is that I am writing a quiz program, and one of the features is that it displays a tick, cross or three dots next to each question depending on whether the user has done it and what their score is.

If the score for that question = 'null' then they haven't yet done it ( display ...)
If the score for that question = 1 then they have done it, and got it right (display tick)
If the score for that question = 0 then they've none it, but got it wrong (display cross)

My actual code is:

```
$score = ($_SESSION['score']);       
         if ($score[$questionList[$loop]['ID']]=='null'){ ?>
             <p style="display:inline;"> ...  </p> <?php } 
         else if ($score[$questionList[$loop]['ID']]==1){ ?>
             <p style="display:inline;"> &#10003  </p> <?php }      
        else if ($score[$questionList[$loop]['ID']]==0){ ?>
             <p style="display:inline;"> X  </p> <?php }  ?>
```

Although it's part of a much bigger page.

I am quite new to PHP, so am probably being incredibly thick here, but any suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the first condition returns true because strings are equal to 0.  See documentation on [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

The solution is to replace your `==` with `===`.  Ex:

```
<?php

$x = 0;

if ($x === 'null'){
    echo 'x is euqal to null';}

else if ($x === 0){ \\true
    echo 'x is equal to zero!';}

else if ($x === 1){
    echo 'x is equal to one!';}

?>
```

Comment: THANKS! This worked great, and I didn't realise strings were equal to zero, but that makes a lot of sense :p Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `null` or the string `'null'`? I would guess that you mean the value `null`, as in nothing. In this case your comparison with `'null'` equals to 0, because you "only" use `==`, you should use strict comparison, which is `===`.

Its good habit not to use `else if`, but `elseif` instead. Read more at [the docs](https://www.php.net/elseif)

You should also work on improving your syntax, its quite confusing.

For your case, i would check for null as the last thing, and not put that in an elseif, but simply let it be the last case. Like this

```
$score = ($_SESSION['score']);       
if ($score[$questionList[$loop]['ID']] === 1)
{
    print '<p style="display:inline;"> &#10003  </p>';
}      
elseif ($score[$questionList[$loop]['ID']] === 0)
{
    print '<p style="display:inline;"> X  </p>';
} 
else
{
    print '<p style="display:inline;"> ...  </p>';
}
```

Opening and closing your php tags all the time is a really bad idea.

Comment: Would result in the same thing, however.

Comment: well I put null in quotes, and I tried using other words other than 'null', like 'zero'. But that didn't work either :/

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting the subtleties of [type juggling:](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

```
var_dump(0 == 'null');
var_dump('0' == 'null');
```

... prints:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

You can do many things but using the [`===`](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator is probably the easiest. Just make sure you are using data types coherenty, i.e., don't mix `0` and `'0'` carelessly.

Comment: type juggling? Sounds awesome, thanks for learning me the expression!

Answer (score 0):

The string 'null' is converted to number when you compare it against a number. See PHP documentation for comparison operators.